# .jar file is not working after being published from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I dont know what I did wrong, this is the first time Im publishing a java project, I just made a simple Hello World application and exported it when I tried to launch it, nothing happens.I tried doing the "java -jar helloworld2124.jar" command in command prompt but i get "Error: Unable to accesss jarfile helloworld2124.jar" message. I even tried doing the "java" command and it didnt show an error message. What should I do?

`public class Workkn1 {`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello World");



}
```

}

 *I tried the "java -jar yourfilename.jar" command but it keeps returning "Error: Unable to accesss jarfile helloworld2124.jar" in the cmd.*

Comment: can you post your full code here

Comment: Main method body? Google how to properly export java project to jar using your ide.

Comment: You should make sure you're at the right current directory.

Comment: my code is: public class Workkn1 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  System.out.println("Hello World");
  
  
  
 }
 
}